# QSerialPort effect on `/dev/ttyS*` after process end?

Tags: linux, qt, file-descriptor, filehandle, qtserialport

When a Qt app using `QSerialPort` experiences a non-clean shutdown (e.g. due to receiving and not handling `SIGINT`), how is the file descriptor of the serial port affected?

After running an app that opens a `QSerialPort` on `/dev/ttyS0`, then quitting with `Ctl-C`, I am finding that `cat < /dev/ttyS0` returns instantly (without printing anything) rather than waiting for data (as it usually does).

I would expect that if this is due to an open file handle left hanging around, it would show up in the output of `lsof`, but `lsof | grep ttyS0` returns nothing. (I'm not really sure how else to search for handles on a particular file descriptor.)

I realize this is a bit of an XY problem, since I could avoid the problem entirely by rewriting my app to properly handle `SIGINT`, but I'd like to have a deeper understanding of what's going on here and if there's a way to recover the serial port when it's in this state.

---

**EDIT:** As requested, here is the output of `strace cat /dev/ttyS0`:

```
execve("/bin/cat", ["cat", "/dev/ttyS0"], [/* 17 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x91ce000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb76fb000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=72063, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 72063, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb76e9000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\240o\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1446056, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 1460600, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb7584000
mmap2(0xb76e3000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x15e) = 0xb76e3000
mmap2(0xb76e6000, 10616, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb76e6000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7583000
set_thread_area({entry_number:-1 -> 6, base_addr:0xb75838d0, limit:1048575, seg_32bit:1, contents:0, read_exec_only:0, limit_in_pages:1, seg_not_present:0, useable:1}) = 0
mprotect(0xb76e3000, 8192, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x8054000, 4096, PROT_READ)    = 0
mprotect(0xb771a000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
munmap(0xb76e9000, 72063)               = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x91ce000
brk(0x91ef000)                          = 0x91ef000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1534672, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 1534672, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb740c000
close(3)                                = 0
fstat64(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 3), ...}) = 0
open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|S_ISVTX|0660, st_rdev=makedev(4, 64), ...}) = 0
fadvise64_64(3, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL) = 0
read(3, "", 32768)                      = 0
close(3)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

And here is the output of `stty -a -F /dev/ttyS0`:

```
speed 57600 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 0; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
-opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
```

Comment: I can tell you that there is definitely *not* an open file handle hanging around: when a process terminates *in any way* (SIGINT, `_exit`, whatever), the kernel automatically closes every file it still had open.  However, there *is* state associated with the terminal itself, rather than any file open on it, that might persist. It would be useful if you could post the output of `strace cat /dev/ttyS0` (**NOT** `strace cat < /dev/ttyS0`) while the terminal is in this state , and also the output of `stty -a -F /dev/ttyS0` before and after putting the terminal in this state.

Comment: @zwol I've added it to the question.

Comment: OK, that confirms that the terminal is left in some sort of wonky state.  How about the `stty -a -F /dev/ttyS0` output, please?

Comment: @zwol Added. By the way, how persistent is baud rate? Is it a property of the port that lasts until the next reboot (or until it is explicitly set to something else)?

Comment: I don't really *know*, I'm just fumbling my way through the manpages along with you.  Does `stty -F /dev/ttyS0 sane` put the terminal back the way it was before the Qt program crashed?

Comment: @zwol ......Yes it does. Interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under POSIX, terminal devices (that is, serial ports and pseudoterminals) have [a whole bunch of settings](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html) which enable the computer to speak the multitude of variations on the basic [RS-232](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232) protocol that exist or have existed.  A great deal of this API was designed back in the days when dinosaurs and [teletypewriters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter) (hence "tty") ruled the earth, and we wouldn't do it over again the same way, but we're stuck with it now.

The terminal settings are persistent; once one program sets them, they stay that way until another program changes them.  The command-line utility [`stty`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/stty.html) can print or change these settings; `stty sane` resets them all to "reasonable" defaults; `stty -a` prints them all out.

Here are all the terminal settings that differ between what `stty sane` applies on my computer, and what `QSerialPort` did to your serial port.  (The ones that are just a cryptic label, possibly with a dash in front, are boolean flags; the leading dash means "off", no leading dash means "on".)

```
  QSerialPort        stty sane    
----------------  ----------------
speed 57600 baud  speed 38400 baud
min = 0           min = 1         
clocal            -clocal         
-brkint           brkint          
ignpar            -ignpar         
-icrnl            icrnl           
-ixon             ixon            
-imaxbel          imaxbel         
-opost            opost           
-isig             isig            
-icanon           icanon          
-iexten           iexten          
-echo             echo
```

Many of the `QSerialPort` settings are abnormal in the sense that a line- or file-oriented program hooked up to a serial port in this state will misbehave.  (However, they are perfectly appropriate for a program that *knows* it is talking to a serial port and is prepared to deal with the consequences of having turned these particular knobs; presumably the authors of `QSerialPort` knew what they were doing.)  The one that is causing `cat` to quit immediately is `min = 0`, which (together with the default `time = 0`) means "`read()` should return zero bytes if there is no input pending."  Under normal circumstances, zero bytes returned from `read()` means *end of file*, so `cat` quits immediately because it thinks it's been handed an empty file.  (This mode may well have been invented years before `O_NONBLOCK`.)

`stty sane` is the "way to recover the serial port" that you were looking for.  The documentation does not say either way, but if `QSerialPort::close()` called from your `SIGINT` handler does *not* restore the terminal to its original state, I would consider that a bug in Qt.  You should also do this upon receipt of `SIGHUP`, `SIGQUIT`, `SIGABRT`, `SIGTERM`, and arguably `SIGTSTP`, `SIGTTIN`, `SIGTTOU` as well (but that's more complicated, because those aren't fatal).  Make sure to restore the default handler and re-raise the signal afterward, so that the exit status is correct.

Comment: Okay, excellent. Since I am in fact just re-running the Qt app over and over rather than actually needing access via `cat`, it looks like I don't even need a "recovery" path; the Qt app should behave the same way each time regardless of whether it's been run before. Since letting the program run to completion and call `close()` does in fact keep `cat` working, I assume that there's no bug after all. Thank you for your help!